# Problem with malloc and/or realloc of a char** pointer of an array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I tried to debug part of a larger code of mine, the code is mainly for testing malloc and realloc of char** on a smaller, more manageable scale with fewer functions.
What I was trying to achieve is store a "debugging_in_progress" string through multiple pointers, each mallocated individually (no shallow copy) and have these pointers stored in a (char**) pointer.
For this example, "texts" starts with a size of 10, then increases to 40 by doubling it twice, and the amount of texts stored in it should be 35 strings.

For debugging purposes, I tried printing out the memory locations themself with the stored string included while putting the pointers into "texts". After all 35 mallocs were done and all pointers were stored, I tried printing them out again to check if anything changed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
void reallocMem(char **currArray, int* maxSize, int currSize);
void memCheck(void ptr);

int main()
{
char debug[100] = "debugging_in_progress";

    int length = strlen(debug);
    char** texts = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char*) * 10);
    int max = 10;
    int c;
    
    for (int i= 0; i < 35; ++i)
    {
        reallocMem(texts,&max,i);
        texts[i] = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * length);
        printf("OG %d.: %p\n",i,texts[i]);
        
        for (int j = 0; j <= length; j++)
        {
            texts[i][j] = debug[j];
        }
        printf("OG %d.TEXT: %s\n",i,texts[i]);
        c++;
    
    }
    
    for (int i = 10; i < 35; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d.:%p\n",i+1,texts[i]);
        // free(texts[i]);
    }
    printf("%d/%d",c,max);
    return 0;

}

void reallocMem(char **currArray, int* maxSize, int currSize)
{
if (currSize >= (*maxSize))
{
(*maxSize) *= 2;
currArray = (char*) realloc(currArray, (*maxSize) * sizeof(char*));
memCheck(currArray);

    }

}

void memCheck(void* ptr)
{
if (!ptr)
{
fprintf(stderr,"Row couldn't be processed: no memory left");
exit(7);
}
}
```

**The problems that I encountered:**
These problems likely come from my misunderstanding of how malloc and realloc actually function.

First, the text below is the output of the code above, which seems to have lost the first 2 pointers to some strings.

Second, when I tried printing out strings (using %s) after storing all pointers, I got Segmentation Fault, even when I tried to "avoid" the seemingly lost pointers (by setting i = 10 for example).

Third, when I tried to set max and it's corresping value when malloc-ing texts to for example 4, I got no erros, nothing, the program just seeming crashed.

**Output of code above:**

"""

▒'}@(}▒&}▒%}▒(})}`(} (}▒&}'} &}▒(}▒(} '}@&}&}`'} )}▒%}ugging_in_progress

OG 3.: 00000208e97d23c0
OG 3.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 4.: 00000208e97d23e0
OG 4.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 5.: 00000208e97d2400
OG 5.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 6.: 00000208e97d2420
OG 6.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 7.: 00000208e97d2440
OG 7.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 8.: 00000208e97d2460
OG 8.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 9.: 00000208e97d2480
OG 9.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 10.: 00000208e97d12f0
OG 10.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 11.: 00000208e97d1310
OG 11.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 12.: 00000208e97d1330
OG 12.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 13.: 00000208e97d2550
OG 13.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 14.: 00000208e97d28a0
OG 14.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 15.: 00000208e97d2940
OG 15.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 16.: 00000208e97d27c0
OG 16.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 17.: 00000208e97d2840
OG 17.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 18.: 00000208e97d26c0
OG 18.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 19.: 00000208e97d25e0
OG 19.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 20.: 00000208e97d2880
OG 20.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 21.: 00000208e97d2900
OG 21.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 22.: 00000208e97d2860
OG 22.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 23.: 00000208e97d2820
OG 23.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 24.: 00000208e97d2680
OG 24.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 25.: 00000208e97d2700
OG 25.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 26.: 00000208e97d2620
OG 26.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 27.: 00000208e97d28c0
OG 27.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 28.: 00000208e97d28e0
OG 28.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 29.: 00000208e97d2720
OG 29.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 30.: 00000208e97d2640
OG 30.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 31.: 00000208e97d2600
OG 31.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 32.: 00000208e97d2760
OG 32.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 33.: 00000208e97d2920
OG 33.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

OG 34.: 00000208e97d25c0
OG 34.TEXT: debugging_in_progress

11.:0000007373657267
12.:00000208e97d1310 13.:00000208e97d1330
14.:00000208e97d2550
15.:00000208e97d28a0
16.:00000208e97d2940
17.:00000208e97d27c0
18.:00000208e97d2840
19.:00000208e97d26c0
20.:00000208e97d25e0
21.:00000208e97d2880
22.:00000208e97d2900
23.:00000208e97d2860
24.:00000208e97d2820
25.:00000208e97d2680
26.:00000208e97d2700
27.:00000208e97d2620
28.:00000208e97d28c0
29.:00000208e97d28e0
30.:00000208e97d2720
31.:00000208e97d2640
32.:00000208e97d2600
33.:00000208e97d2760
34.:00000208e97d2920
35.:00000208e97d25c0
35/40

"""

Comment: You are setting the size of the allocation to `2` unconditionally here: `(*maxSize) = 2;`. Also `currSize` isn't actually the current size of the allocation.

Comment: I do not understand why are you doing `c++` without initialising `c`.

Comment: looks like leftover code. `c` is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Some good rules when doing C programming:

1. Set a high compiler warning level
2. Fix all warnings before executing the program

For the gcc compiler I'll recommend (at least) these options: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`

The `-Werror` turns all warnings into errors and thereby helps you remember rule #2 above.

Now a direct copy of your code and a compiled with gcc 12.1.0 and `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` gives me:

```
error: parameter 1 ('ptr') has void type [-Werror]
    6 | void memCheck(void ptr);
      |               ~~~~~^~~
In function 'main':
error: passing argument 1 of 'reallocMem' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   19 |         reallocMem(texts,&max,i);
      |                    ^~~~~
      |                    |
      |                    char **
note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char **'
    5 | void reallocMem(char *currArray, int* maxSize, int currSize);
      |                 ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
At top level:
error: conflicting types for 'reallocMem'; have 'void(char **, int *, int)'
   42 | void reallocMem(char **currArray, int* maxSize, int currSize)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
note: previous declaration of 'reallocMem' with type 'void(char *, int *, int)'
    5 | void reallocMem(char *currArray, int* maxSize, int currSize);
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
In function 'reallocMem':
error: assignment to 'char **' from incompatible pointer type 'char *' [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   47 | currArray = (char*) realloc(currArray, (*maxSize) * sizeof(char*));
      |           ^
error: too many arguments to function 'memCheck'
   48 | memCheck(currArray);
      | ^~~~~~~~
note: declared here
    6 | void memCheck(void ptr);
      |      ^~~~~~~~
At top level:
error: conflicting types for 'memCheck'; have 'void(void *)'
   54 | void memCheck(void* ptr)
      |      ^~~~~~~~
note: previous declaration of 'memCheck' with type 'void(void)'
    6 | void memCheck(void ptr);
      |      ^~~~~~~~
```

**All these must be fixed before running the program**.

It only requires 3 small changes

```
#include <string.h>
void reallocMem(char *currArray, int* maxSize, int currSize);
void memCheck(void ptr);
```

to

```
#include <string.h>
void reallocMem(char **currArray, int* maxSize, int currSize);
void memCheck(void *ptr);
```

and

```
currArray = (char*) realloc(currArray, (*maxSize) * sizeof(char*));
```

to

```
currArray = (char**) realloc(currArray, (*maxSize) * sizeof(char*));
```

er better, just don't do a cast.

```
currArray = realloc(currArray, (*maxSize) * sizeof(char*));
```

Now the program compiles without errors but there are still (at least) two problems.

```
(*maxSize) = 2;
```

isn't doubling but constantly assign two. You probably wanted:

```
(*maxSize) *= 2;
```

The next problem is a common beginners mistake. Look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int x)
{
    x = 42;
    printf("In foo: x=%d\n", x);
}
int main(void) 
{
    int x = 5;
    printf("In start of main: x=%d\n", x);
    foo(x);
    printf("Back start of main: x=%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives:

```
In start of main: x=5
In foo: x=42
Back start of main: x=5
```

As you can see the value of `x` is changed to 42 inside `foo` but as soon as we get back in `main` the value is still 5. This is because `foo` gets a copy of the value of `x` in `main`. So the two `x` variables are completely independent and changing `x` in `foo` will not change `x` in `main`.

You have exactly that problem with `reallocMem`. You pass `text` to `currArray` and then you store the return value from `realloc` into `currArray`. Fine... but it will **not** change the value of `text` in `main`.

To change `text` you need to pass a pointer to `text`. Like:

```
void reallocMem(char ***currArray, int* maxSize, int currSize)
{
    if (currSize >= (*maxSize))
    {
        (*maxSize) = *2;
        *currArray = realloc(*currArray, (*maxSize) * sizeof(char*));
    }
}
```

and call it like:

```
reallocMem(&texts, &max, i);
```

In fact this is no different from the way you handled `max`.

And yes, you are now officially a three-star-programmer

Two minor things at the end...

In your `malloc`/`realloc` you always use sizeof(type-name), for instance

```
 TYPE* x = malloc(N * sizeof(TYPE));
```

So you write `TYPE` two times which opens for bugs if you don't do it correct. A better way is to use the variable name like

```
 TYPE* x = malloc(N * sizeof(*x));
```

And again: Don't cast malloc

Last thing:

`realloc` may return a NULL pointer. Therefore it's recommended to `realloc` into a temp variable and check for NULL before assigning to the real target variable. Like

```
        char** temp = realloc(*currArray, (*maxSize) * sizeof(char*));
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            // Out of memory! Add error handling
        }
        else
        {
            // All good
            *currArray = temp;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Most of the problems you mentioned in the beginning are because of my inattention during copy pasting the code, because I didn't notice some of the * got left out. I am very sorry about that.

Right now my example/testing code seems to be working with the suggestions you said, although my main code still needs some refinement it seems. I might post an update on here later.